# How do I read 青水庵 as a name?

Tags: kanji, pronunciation, names

Recently, I found a nickname, 青水庵 on the internet. How do you read this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I read it `[青水庵]{せいすいあん}` if there's no hint.

But, I googled this name and found an [illustrator](http://aomizuan.sakura.ne.jp/) (NSFW) who calls himself `[青水庵]{あおみずあん}`.

### Why I read せいすいあん first?

`庵` can be read as either `あん` and `いおり`. In case of this, since `庵` occurs directly after other kanji in a group, the general rule is to read all kanji  using the Chinese pronunciation ([音読]{おんよ}み) in general. e.g. [吉兆庵](https://www.kitchoan.co.jp/site/) (きっちょうあん)